# How to check Windows Defender status via the command line?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, security, windows-defender

How can I check and make sure that all Windows Defender shields and protection are on/active and that everything has a green tick:

[image]

via the Windows 10's *command prompt*?

---

#### Edit #1:

Per [@JG7](https://superuser.com/users/623588)'s and [@harrymc](https://superuser.com/users/8672/)'s answer, I tried `Get-MpComputerStatus` command in powershell, however I received this error output:

```
Get-MpComputerStatus : A general error occurred that is not covered by a more specific error code.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-MpComputerStatus
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_MpComputerStatus:ROOT\Microsoft\...pComputerStatus) [Get-MpComputerSta
   tus], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x800106ba,Get-MpComputerStatus
```

Comment: PowerShell can do this. `Get-MpComputerStatus | select AntivirusEnabled` This will be a nice read for you: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52251.manage-windows-defender-using-powershell.aspx

Comment: @JG7 unfortunately I got an error running the command. See the full error messsage in my original post (under `Edit #1`)

Comment: Do you get the same error while running PowerShell as admin?

Comment: @JG7 Yes, I tried to execute the command with a PowerShell as an Administrator and have same exact error message.

Comment: that exception code is so obscure. I did some searching on Google and this was one item that popped up. It’s not the exact case, but may set you on the right path. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48960190/powershell-set-mppreference-disablerealtimemonitoring-true-not-working-correct

Answer (score 3):

Use PowerShell to get the Windows Defender status information.

The command to use is
[Get-MpComputerStatus](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/defender/get-mpcomputerstatus?view=win10-ps).
It reports the status of Windows Defender services,
signature versions, last update, last scan, and more.

This is the output of the command (as copied from the above link):

```
PS C:\> Get-MpComputerStatus
AMEngineVersion                 : 1.1.9700.0
AMProductVersion                : 4.3.9463.0
AMServiceEnabled                : True
AMServiceVersion                : 4.3.9463.0
AntispywareEnabled              : True
AntispywareSignatureAge         : 0
AntispywareSignatureLastUpdated : 7/30/2013 3:01:45 AM
AntispywareSignatureVersion     : 1.155.1107.0
AntivirusEnabled                : True
AntivirusSignatureAge           : 0
AntivirusSignatureLastUpdated   : 7/30/2013 3:01:45 AM
AntivirusSignatureVersion       : 1.155.1107.0
BehaviorMonitorEnabled          : True
ComputerID                      : A69DA5B8-06B3-4A00-B2C1-D18ED66BAD40
ComputerState                   : 0
FullScanAge                     : 4294967295
FullScanEndTime                 :
FullScanStartTime               :
IoavProtectionEnabled           : True
LastFullScanSource              : 0
LastQuickScanSource             : 2
NISEnabled                      : False
NISEngineVersion                : 2.1.9700.0
NISSignatureAge                 : 0
NISSignatureLastUpdated         : 7/30/2013 1:30:46 PM
NISSignatureVersion             : 106.0.0.0
OnAccessProtectionEnabled       : True
QuickScanAge                    : 0
QuickScanEndTime                : 7/30/2013 1:50:24 PM
QuickScanStartTime              : 7/30/2013 1:49:15 PM
RealTimeProtectionEnabled       : True
RealTimeScanDirection           : 0
```

For more information see
[Manage Windows Defender using PowerShell](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52251.manage-windows-defender-using-powershell.aspx).

Comment: I got a an error running the command in powershell on my machine: `Get-MpComputerStatus : A general error occurred that is not covered by a more specific error code.`

Comment: Added the full error message in the original post (under `Edit #1`)

Comment: This works for me. Is Windows Defender enabled on the computer? Run the following: `(Get-Service windefend).Status` that should return "Running". For starting the service: `Start-Service windefend`. Some other anti-malware products may disable Windows Defender and prevent the service from starting.

Comment: Running `(Get-Service windefend).Status`, it tells me that it is `Stopped`. I tried `Start-Service windefend` but it `Failed to start service`. Yet, my Windows Defender show all green ticks (as seen in the post).

Comment: What do you get for: `Get-Command -Module Defender`? You should get a list that includes `Get-MpComputerStatus`. Also, what is your Windows 10 version?

Answer (score 2):

This command gives information about antiviruses on Windows. Run this command on the command prompt.

`WMIC /Node:localhost /Namespace:\\root\SecurityCenter2 Path AntiVirusProduct  Get displayName,timestamp /Format:List`

Explanation : All the antiviruses (inbuilt and third party) will be listed alongwith their names and version update time stamp.Doesn't require elevation.

Comment: Code without any explanation is useless. 
Can you elaborate on this a little more?